# How to query JSONB column (storing array of objects) in Postgresql using sequelize in nodejs?

Tags: node.js, postgresql, orm, sequelize.js, jsonb

I have a JSONB-type column named `contributors` in my table, where I store an array of Objects, 
Ex:

```
[{"user_id" : 1 , name : "user1" , ...} , {"user_id" : 2, name : "user2", ...} ,...]
```

I query the records which for a particular user_id in `contributors` using the Sequelize ORM.
Currently, as per the sequelize docs, I am querying like this:

```
const findUserRecords = 
await MyTable.find({where : {contributors: {user_id: 1 }}});
```

Is this the right way to query a JSONB using a sequelize model or am I doing anything wrong here?